how to replace one action in the ecoinvent database in Brightway2.5 with another action
I copied an activity for electricity in ecoinvent and changed this activity and replaced it with more up-to-date data, now I want to replace the old activity in the entire ecoinvent database with my new one, how can I do this?

why not just edit the activity you want to change, instead of copying it. this would be easier for you.
